# Involutions on Moduli space of curves $C_{g,[n]} \to M_{g,[n]}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $M_{g,[n]}$ be the moduli space of curves over complex number with level-$n$ structure. It is known that when $n\geq 3$, there is a universal family of curves over it: $f:\,C_{g,[n]} \to M_{g,[n]}$. There is a natural involution $\tau$ on $M_{g,[n]}$ defined by $\tau\big([C, \alpha]\big) = [C,-\alpha]$, where $C$ is a curve, $\alpha$ is a level structure, and $[C,\alpha]$ is the corresponding point in $M_{g,[n]}$. The fixed points are exactly corresponding to the hyperelliptic locus $H_{g,[n]}$. (See Oort, F.; Steenbrink, J.;
{The local Torelli problem for algebraic curves},
Journ\'ees de G\'eometrie Alg\'ebrique d'Angers, (1979), 157--204.)

My question is that, Is there an involution $\sigma$ on $C_{g,[n]}$ such that: (i) $f\circ \sigma=\tau\circ f$; (ii) $\tau|_{C_p}$ is the hyperelliptic involution of $C_p$, where $p\in H_{g,[n]}$ and $C_p \subseteq C_{g,[n]}$ the fiber over $p$.

Comment: Is $n$ equal to $2$ in your question?

Comment: $n\geq 3$. The question is to ask the existence of $\sigma$ on $C_{g,[n]}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. $C_{g,[n]}$ is a fine moduli space for curves  with one marked point + level $n$ structure. Just define $\sigma $ by $\sigma  ([C,p,\alpha ])=[C,p,-\alpha ]$. If $C$ is hyperelliptic,  the hyperelliptic involution $\iota $ induces an isomorphism $[C,p,-\alpha ]\cong [C,\iota (p), \alpha ]$, so $\sigma _{|C}=\iota $.

Comment: ： Thank you very much. But I am confused about your construction. By your definition, $\sigma([C,p,\alpha])=[C,p,-\alpha]$. Then what I learned is that $\sigma$ should be identity map on the hyperelliptic locus, since $\sigma([C,p,\alpha])=[C,p,-\alpha]=[C,p,\alpha]$ if $C$ is hyperelliptic.

Comment: The point is, why do you have $[C,\alpha ]\cong [C,-\alpha ]$ in the hyperelliptic case? Because the hyperelliptic involution $\iota $ provides an isomorphism $C\rightarrow C$ with $\iota \circ\alpha =-\alpha $. Now on $C_{g,[n]}$, $\iota $ gives an isomorphism  $[C,p,\alpha ]\cong [C,\iota (p),-\alpha ]$.

Comment: OK, I see the point. Thank you. By the way, Is there any reference about this point?

Comment: About your specific question, none that I know of -- Oort-Steenbrink that you mention is the closest.

Comment: I have a question about your answer. I think $C_{g,[n]}$ is not the moduli space for curves with one marked point+level structure. Let me denote by $M_{g,[n],1}$ the later space. The reason is the following. If a curve $C$ has a non-trivial automorphism group $G$. Then $[C,p,\alpha]$ and $[C,\tau(p),\alpha]$ represent the same point of $M_{g,[n],1}$ for any $\tau \in G$. This implies that the fibre of $M_{g,[n],1} \to M_{g,[n]}$ over $[C,\alpha]\in M_{g,[n]}$ is isomorphic to $C/G$. But the universe family $C_{g,[n]} \to M_{g,[n]}$ requires that the fibre over $[C,\alpha]$ isomorphicto C

Comment: No, $[C,p,\alpha ]$ is not the same point as  $[C,\tau (p),\alpha ]$, but as $[C,\tau (p),\tau ^*\circ\alpha ]$.